# How to activate a function as soon as the client/user enters the site

Tags: javascript, onload

I want to be able to call `myFunction` as soon as I enter my site. how can I do this?

```
    function myFunction() {
        myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, 3000);
    }

    function alertFunc() {
        alert("Hello!");
    })
```

Comment: [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) seems to a solution to your problem. Another useful event is [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function alertFunc() {
    alert("Hello!");
}

window.onload = function() {
 myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, 3000);
};
```

Comment: alertFunc will be executed after the page is completely loaded. If you want to execute it even before it loads, you should use the David Anderton's solution

Answer (score 2):

just add the call to `myFunction` at the end - I don't believe you are actually calling your function, only defining them:

```js
function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, 3000);
}

function alertFunc() {
  alert("Hello!");
}

myFunction();
```

Also you had a syntax error of an extra bracket `)` at the end of the `alertFunc()` definition.

Answer (score 1):

Execute a JavaScript immediately after a page has been loaded by filling **onload** field of body.

Here is some example code:

```
<html>
    <body onload="myFunction()">
        <script>
        function myFunction() {
            //here put your immediate action e.g.
            alert("Page is fully loaded");
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```